# Setting the value of a $scope variable with data from pouchDB in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise, pouchdb

I have this AngularJS factory.

```
angular.module('app.factories', [])
.factory('ProgressDBFactory', function () {
    var factory = {};
    var pouchDb = new PouchDB('ProgressDB');

    factory.getAllData = function() {
        var dbOptions = {};
        dbOptions.include_docs = true;

        return pouchDb.allDocs(dbOptions).then(function(res) {
            return res.rows;
        });
    };

    return factory;
})
```

I need to set the `$scope.progressData` in my controller with the data coming from pouchDb. My Controller looks like this.

```
.controller('ProgressController', function($scope, ProgressDBFactory) {

    $scope.progressData = {};

    var progPromise = ProgressDBFactory.getAllProgressData();

    progPromise.then(function(res) {
        $scope.progressData = res;
        console.log($scope.progressData); // POINT A <= Here it prints all the results from the database.
    });

    console.log($scope.progressData); // POINT B <= here it just prints an empty object

})
```

At POINT A it correctly prints the result from the db. But in POINT B it prints an empty object. Also, in the console POINT B prints before POINT A gets printed. This suggests to me that POINT B is executed before the promise has finished executing. Am I right? I'm new to javascript and this doesn't make sense to me. Can some one clarify this and give a solution. Please help

Comment: I assume the "getAllProgressData" refers to "getAllData" function in the factory.

Comment: More than that, I seems that your code is resolving the promise twice and the factory is both returning the promise and the resolved promise (inside the then). However, if you get the data printed in the "POINT A" isn't it displayed in the view (html) anyway?

Comment: I produced this simple jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5j0kf0eo/1/ to indicate, that as for producing the value to the view, your code should be already working.

Comment: The problem is i need to feed that data i take from the IndexedDb in to a chart and that chart is then set as a $scope variable in the controller which is bind to the HTML View. Since the $scope.progressData is not available out side (at POINT B and beyond) I can't set the other $scope variables by processing the values taken from the DB

Comment: I am afraid I still don't see the problem clearly, you should expose more code as of what you are trying to achieve... the progressData variable *is* available for entire $scope. If process the latest value in from the database, then do them inside of a callback. I updated the fiddle now to display consecutive poll data http://jsfiddle.net/5j0kf0eo/2/

Comment: @KasunKodagoda, you have discovered asynchronism. Your code behaves exactly as one would expect given that `ProgressDBFactory.getAllProgressData()` returns not results *per se* but a promise of results - ie an object with a `.then()` method that will reveal data when it arrives *asynchronously*.

Comment: So should i access the promise with .then() in the factory and then return the result to my controller? I kinda tried that.. But that too had no effect. How can i wait for the result of the promise..

Comment: Only promise methods can wait for promised results. Any statement following `ProgressDBFactory.getAllProgressData()`, whether it is in the same function or in that function's caller, is guaranteed to execute before the promised data had been delivered. In short, asynchronously derived data cannot be handled synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Point B will always happen before point A, since point A is wrapped inside a callback from an asynchronous call (promise) to the DB. There is nothing wrong with your code as far as execution order goes. Although you would probably have to wrap your scope assignment inside a $apply since you are executing it outside Angular context (as far as I know it's a callback from a 3rd party library).

```
progPromise.then(function(res) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
       $scope.progressData = res;
       console.log($scope.progressData); // POINT A <= Here it prints all the results from the database.
    })
});
```

More info on $apply: [AngularJS Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it did not work. Not the log message inside the $scope.apply() does not print to the console.

Answer (score 0):

```html
(function(scp){
 progPromise.then(function(res) {
        scp.progressData = res;
        console.log(scp.progressData); // POINT A <= Here it prints all the results from the database.
    });
 console.log($scope.progressData);
    
})($scope);
```

Hope this might work.

Answer (score 0):

```html
(function(scp){
 progPromise.then(function(res) {
        scp.progressData = res;
        console.log(scp.progressData); // POINT A <= Here it prints all the results from the database.
    });
 console.log($scope.progressData);
    
})($scope);
```

Comment: it did not work bro, Same result. Can you tell me a way to wait till the promise is complete?